# Форма приема заявок + калькулятор со сложной логикой расчетов

Tags: javascript, html, html-form, калькулятор

Ниже приводятся чекбоксы формы с требованиями к ним. Чекбоксы, отделенные друг от друга подчеркиванием — это отдельные блоки в форме.

Форма приведена [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/alegraft/4by4agw3/). Атрибут `name="option[]"` просьба не изменять - с его помощью, через php, форма сохраняется в файл на сервере.

Как должно работать:

```
Пункт 01 - 100 руб.
Пункт 02 - 200 руб.

* Если человек выбирает "Пункт 01", то платит 100 руб.
* Если человек выбирает "Пункт 02", то автоматически отмечается и "Пункт 01", с оплатой за всё 200 руб.
______________________________

Пункт 03 - 100 руб.
Пункт 04 - 200 руб.
Пункт 05 - 300 руб.

* Если человек выбирает "Пункт 03", то платит 100 руб.
* Если человек выбирает "Пункт 04", то автоматически отмечается и "Пункт 03", с оплатой за всё 100 руб.
* Если человек выбирает "Пункт 05", то автоматически отмечается и "Пункт 03", с оплатой за всё 300 руб.
______________________________
```

В данный момент калькулятор работает, но он все суммирует.
В голову приходит только такая идея:

1. Присвоить каждому пункту уникальный ID, и, в зависимости от нажатого чекбокса, включать зависимый чекбокс.
2. Цена при этом берется от основного чекбокса.
3. В итоги блоков суммируются.

Вопрос: как сделать один чекбокс зависимым от другого?

Пример:

```js
var Calculator = {
  selectedGroups: [],
  sum: 0,

  isGroupSelected: function(groupId) {
    return this.selectedGroups.indexOf(groupId) != -1;
  },

  addSelected: function(groupId, amount) {
    if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
      this.changeSum(amount);
    }
    this.selectedGroups.push(groupId);
  },

  removeSelected: function(groupId, amount) {
    if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
      return;
    }
    var groupIndex = this.selectedGroups.indexOf(groupId);
    this.selectedGroups.splice(groupIndex, 1);
    if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
      this.changeSum(-amount);
    }
  },

  onSelect: function(groupId, amount, elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
      this.addSelected(groupId, amount);
    } else {
      this.removeSelected(groupId, amount);
    }
  },

  changeSum: function(amount) {
    this.sum += amount;
    this.showSum();
  },

  showSum: function() {
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = this.sum;
    document.getElementById('def_sum').value = document.getElementById('r').innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
#table-zay {
  width: 450px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table-zay td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table-text {
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold", 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.table-text-2 {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold", 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form id="message" method="post" action="oplata.php" name="sentPrjForm">

  <table id="table-zay">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 100, this)" value="Пункт 01" />Пункт 01
      </td>
      <td class="table-text-2">100 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(2, 200, this)" value="Пункт 02" />Пункт 02
      </td>
      <td class="table-text-2">200 руб.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />

  <table id="table-zay">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 100, this)" value="Пункт 03" />Пункт 03
      </td>
      <td class="table-text-2">100 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(2, 200, this)" value="Пункт 04" />Пункт 04
      </td>
      <td class="table-text-2">200 руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(3, 300, this)" value="Пункт 05" />Пункт 05
      </td>
      <td class="table-text-2">300 руб.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />

  <div class="formInputBlock">
    <br />
    <b>Итоговая стоимость:</b>  <span id="r" name="def_sum">0</span> руб.
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" id="def_sum" name="def_sum">
    <br />
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="/images/00.gif" width="1" height="15" alt="" border="0" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Оплатить заявку" />

</form>
```

Comment: а в чем заключается ваш вопрос? :-)

Comment: @alegraft, помочь, это не значит: сделать за вас, кроме того, ваш вопрос не представляет ценности никакому пользователю кроме вас.

Comment: Ну и повторюсь: в чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: так же стоит добавить в сам вопрос: разметку и js код который есть у вас

Comment: @Grundy, Простыня получается. Но сделал, в дополнение к jsfiddle.

Comment: «У меня другой профиль, в котором я регулярно помогаю людям бесплатно» — если это профиль на ru.stackoverflow.com, то почему вы не задаете вопрос с него?

Comment: @alegraft, в вопрос можно вставлять сниппеты, которые могут скрываться и разворачиваться по требованию

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, Профиль - в смысле профессия и хобби в оффлайне.

Comment: @Grundy, Благодарю, теперь буду знать.

Comment: @alegraft: а, понял вас. Уже привык, что профилем называют учетную запись.